# Detecting Web Service Call Origin in WCF

Tags: wcf

I have a WCF web service. I want to restrict calls to this service to a single page in my application. This page is publicly facing. Is there any way I can check to see where the call to this web service came from? I would like to say something like if (ThisRequestCameFromThisPage()) { goAhead(); }

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something similar to MAC validation.  Server-side, create some type of encrypted token and have it embedded in the hidden form element, javascript variable, etc. -- point being during rendering on the server, embed it in the page so it can be retrieved via the javascript that will call the WCF service.  Pass the token into the call, and validate on the server side.

Things that should be inside the encrypted token should be stuff like IP address of client (REMOTE_ADDR) and a date/time to be able to expire the token.  The token is encrypted and decrypted only on the server, so a decent key should keep the data safe.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the referrer of the Request object. But this is very easily spoofed, and should not be relied on.